# Use Two Sets of Code Formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

I'm a picky programmer with specific preferences for brace placement and other formatting options. My company is picky about formatting too, and has different ideas about code aesthetics.

Is there a way to save two different sets of code formatting in Visual Studio? I would love to be able to use one keyboard shortcut when I load a file to format the file with my preferences, then use a different shortcut before I save it to format it to the company's standards.

Comment: You can export the settings for code formatting, but I'm not sure of a way to load them via keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I followed:

- Set the formatting settings for configuration 1 (Tools > Options > Text Editor...)
- Export the settings (Tools > Import and Export Settings > Choose specific settings...) (Note: Save it in a directory without any spaces in the filepath!)
- Repeat for configuration 2
- Install Visual Commander (https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/)
- Create a new command (VCMD > Commands > Add) (Change path and file name)

  ```
  using EnvDTE;
  using EnvDTE80;

  public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
  {
      public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
      {
          DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/import:C:/Users/{user.name}/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/VisualStudio/14.0/{settingFileName}.vssettings");
          DTE.ActiveDocument.Activate();
          DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument");
          DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveSelectedItems");
      }
  }
  ```
- Repeat for configuration 2
- Map VCmd.Command01 and VCmd.Command02 to keyboard shortcuts (Tools > Options > Enviornment > Keyboard > Vcmd.Command01...)

It works great, but unfortunately depends on an extension. The nice thing is that you can configure as many formatting schemes as you want. Hope it helps someone!